# Is there a better way to get arguments for controller in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

In cakePHP, there is a default way to pass arguments to controller. For example, if this is my controller method:

```
public function index($arg1 = "asia", $arg2 = "HK") {
    // controller code
}
```

In cakePHP, the default URL to this method with parameter is:

http://link.to.my.host/public/testcontroller/method/arg1/arg2/

However, in laravel, to pass the arguments, I will need to add this line to the route.php

```
Route::any("test/{arg1}/{arg2}", "TestController@index");
```

The problem is that I have more than 10 controllers with a few methods in each of them, all receiving the same argument.(The parameter is for language settings) It would be annoying to write 30+ lines to handle these cases and not to mention adding arguments/methods/controllers as the project grows. Is there a way to use just a few lines to tell laravel that arg1 and arg2 will be set for all methods of all controllers? (or at least all methods in particular controller?)

I know I can handle the things with get parameter, but I don't want to as this makes the URL looks ugly. As I would like the user to be able to copy the language settings while copying the URL, post method is not an option.

Comment: use post rather get method. so no need to set params in url and get posted data on controller

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I would like the user be able to copy the parameter when the copy the link. (as this is for language settings) It would be too complicated for the user to copy post parameters. I would add this to the question.